# Prove that any two curves having the same initial and terminal point are homotopic in a simply connected domain in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, homotopy-theory

Let $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ be two paths having initial point $a$ and terminal point $b$ in $D \subseteq \Bbb C.$ Let the parameter interval for both the curves be taken as $I = [0,1].$ Then we say that $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are **homotopic** to each other if there exists a continuous map $H : I \times I \longrightarrow D$ such that the following two conditions are satisfied $:$

$(1)$ $H(0,t) = \gamma_1(t)$ and $H(1,t) = \gamma_2(t),$ for all $t \in I.$

$(2)$ $H(u,0) = a$ and $H(u,1) = b,$ for all $u \in I.$

In such case we write $\gamma_1 \simeq \gamma_2.$

If $\gamma$ is a curve in $D$ with the same initial and the terminal point we say that $\gamma$ is a **closed curve** in $D.$ If it is homotopic to  a point in $D$ then we say that $\gamma$ is **null-homotopic** and we write $\gamma \simeq 0.$ The domain $D \subseteq \Bbb C$ is said to be **simply connected** if every closed curve in $D$ is null-homotopic.

Now let $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ be two curves in a simply connected domain $D \subseteq \Bbb C$ having the same initial point $a$ (say) and the same terminal point $b$ (say). Then can we say that $\gamma_1 \simeq \gamma_2\ $?

Consider the curve $- \gamma_2$ (the curve which has the same image as that of $\gamma_2$ but traced out in the direction as opposed to the curve $\gamma_2$). Then $(\gamma_1 - \gamma_2)$ (the concatenation of $\gamma_1$ and $-\gamma_2$) is a closed curve in $D$ based at $a.$ Since $D$ is simply connected there exists a point $c \in D$ such that $(\gamma_1 - \gamma_2) \simeq c.$ But since $D$ is a domain so $a \simeq c,$ the polygonal path joining $a$ to $c$ being the underlying homotopy. Since homotopy is an equivalence relation it follows that $(\gamma_1 - \gamma_2) \simeq a.$ Let $H$ be the homotopy between $(\gamma_1 - \gamma_2)$ and $a.$ Then $H(u,t) + \gamma_2 (t)$ gives us the homotopy between $(\gamma_1 - \gamma_2) + \gamma_2$ (the concatenation of $(\gamma_1 - \gamma_2)$ and $\gamma_2$) and $a + \gamma_2$ (the concatenation of the constant closed curve based at $a$ and $\gamma_2$), where $u,t \in I.$ Now it is easy to draw a homotopy between $a + \gamma_2$ and $\gamma_2.$ The idea is to reduce the waiting time at $a.$ For that we define $\Gamma_u : I \longrightarrow D$ for all $u \in I$ by
$$
\Gamma_u(t) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            a & \quad t \in \left [0, \frac {1-u} {2} \right ] \\
            \gamma_2 \left ( \frac {2t - 1 + u} {1 + u} \right ) & \quad t \in \left [ \frac {1-u} {2} , 1 \right ]
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Now let us define a map $F : I \times I \longrightarrow D$ by $$F(u,t) = \Gamma_u (t),\ u,t \in I.$$ Then $F$ gives the required homotopy between $a + \gamma_2$ and $\gamma_2.$ Now what about $(\gamma_1 - \gamma_2) + \gamma_2\ $? Is it homotopic to $\gamma_1\ $? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** $:$ It is easy to see that $(\gamma_1 - \gamma_2) + \gamma_2 \simeq \gamma_1 + (-\gamma_2 + \gamma_2).$ For each $u \in I$ consider the maps $\Delta_u : I \longrightarrow D$ defined by $$
\Delta_u(t) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \gamma_1 \left ( \frac {4t} {1 + u} \right ) & \quad t \in \left [0, \frac {1+u} {4} \right ] \\
            (-\gamma_2) \left ( 4t - u - 1 \right ) = \gamma_2 \left (2 + u - 4t \right ) & \quad t \in \left [ \frac {1+u} {4} , \frac {2+u} {4} \right ] \\
\gamma_2 \left (\frac {4t - u - 2} {2 - u} \right ) & \quad t \in \left [\frac {2 + u} {4}, 1 \right ]
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Now consider the map $\Delta : I \times I \longrightarrow D$ defined by $$\Delta (u,t) = \Delta_u(t),\ u,t \in I.$$ Then $\Delta$ gives the required homotopy between $(\gamma_1 -\gamma_2) + \gamma_2$ and $\gamma_1 + (-\gamma_2 + \gamma_2).$

Now we are in a simply connected domain $D$ so $(-\gamma_2 + \gamma_2)$ being a closed curve in $D$ based at $b$ it is homotopic to $b.$ So we get $\gamma_1 + (-\gamma_2 + \gamma_2) \simeq \gamma_1 + b.$ But again by reducing the time of waiting at the point $b$ we can say that $\gamma_1 + b \simeq \gamma_1.$ So by using the fact that homotopy is an equivalence relation we find that $(\gamma_1 - \gamma_2) + \gamma_2 \simeq \gamma_1$ and we are through.

Comment: $-\gamma_2+\gamma_2$ is always homotopic to a constant loop, regardless of simple-connectedness - you should try to prove it !

Comment: Does $\gamma \simeq 0$ mean that the homotopy keeps $x_ 0 = \gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$ fixed? If notation is consistent with $\gamma_1 \simeq \gamma_2$ it should.

Comment: @Paul Frost $\gamma \simeq 0 \implies \gamma$ is null-homotopic or in other words $\gamma$ is homotopic to a point.

Comment: @Paul Frost when I'm saying $\gamma$ is null-homotopic I assume that $\gamma$ is a closed curve. So indeed we have $\gamma (0) = \gamma (1).$

Comment: Of course, but what does $\gamma$ homotopic to a point mean? There are various interpretations for the homotopy $ H : \gamma \simeq 0$. (1) It could be consistent with your definition of $\gamma_1 \simeq \gamma_2$ which would  mean that $0$ is the  constant map $t \mapsto x_0 = \gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$. In that case $H(u,0) = H(u,1) = x_0$ for all $u$. (2) It could  mean that $0$ is any constant map and $\xi_u= H(u,0) = H(u,1)$ for all $u$ (i.e. all intermediate curves are closed), but we do not require that $\xi_u$ is fixed.

Comment: (3) It could mean that $H$ is any null-homotopy and it is allowed that the intermediate curves are not closed. If that is not clarified, you cannot expect an answer.

Comment: @Paul Frost when I say $\gamma$ is homotopic to a point then I mean that it is homotopic to a constant map. This is the definition given in my book. Here since $D$ is a domain in the complex plane any two points lying in it is polygonally connected and hence any two constant maps are homotopic because the polygonal path itself gives a continuous homotopy between any two constant map. Am I right?

Comment: @Paul Frost here by the word **homotopy** I mean **Fixed Endpoint Homotopy**. So here I don't consider any intermediate curve whose endpoints keep on changing in the homotopy;  rather the endpoints are kept fixed in the entire process. Look at my definition of homotopy at the very beginning of my discussion. I think you have missed that. Then such kind of confusion wouldn't arise.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi can it be possible to continuously deform $(-\gamma_2 + \gamma_2)$ to the constant loop at $b$ by not allowing the initial point of $\gamma_2$ i.e. $a$ to vary in the entire process of deformation? My idea is to shrink the closed path $(-\gamma_2 + \gamma_2)$ towards $b.$ But the problem is that then the homotopy doesn't fix the endpoints in the intermediate steps which violates my definition of **homotopy** which I mentioned at the very beginning of my discussion in the body of the qurstion.

Comment: Yes, it's possible

Comment: Can you help me finding it out @MaximeRamzi?

Comment: At least can you share me your idea @MaximeRamzi?

Comment: If $\gamma$ is any path, say from $x$ to $y$, then $\gamma+(-\gamma)$ is a loop from $x$ to itself. For any $s$, let $\gamma_s (t) = \gamma(st)$, and let $H_s = \gamma_s + (-\gamma_s)$. It's pretty easy to check continuity, moreover for $s=0, \gamma_s$ is constant at $x$, therefore so is $-\gamma_s$ (not to be mistaken with $(-\gamma)_s$), and so is $H_s$. When $s=1$, $\gamma_s = \gamma$. Finally, for any $s$, $H_s(0) = \gamma_s(0) = \gamma(0)$ and $H_s(1) = -\gamma_s(1)= \gamma_s(0) = \gamma(0)$

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Thanks a lot for your kind help. Very nice and elegent answer indeed +1.

Comment: @Phibetakappa I disagree, confusion arises  because you have two definitions which are not really compatible. (1) You have a definition of $\gamma_ 1 \simeq \gamma_2$ for  two paths having the same initial point $a$ and the same terminal point $b$ in $D$. (2) For a closed curve $\gamma$ you define $\gamma \simeq 0$ if it is it is **homotopic to a point in $D$**. It is obvious, though not explicitly mentioned, that "a point" has to be understood as "a constant path in $D$". But as long as you do not explicitly say that **a point in $D$** is not an arbitrary point,

Comment: but the special point $x_0 = \gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$, it  is not all clear that that definition (1) should be taken. In fact, an (alternative) standard approach is to consider loops in $X$ (which are maps $f : S^1 \to X$) and to say that $X$ is simply connected if it is path connected and each loop is null-homotopic which does not require that the basepoint $1 \in S^1$ is kept fixed under the contracting homotopy. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space